# Screen brightness is not responding to brightness control

Tags: laptop, drivers, brightness, 120hz, acer

I have recently replaced my 60Hz laptop screen with a 120Hz one
And now screen brightness is not responding to brightness control (e.g. When i set the brightness value to 0%, the actual brightness doesn't change)

- My laptop model is Acer Nitro 5 AN515-53 running on windows 10 Home latest version
- No Windows updates are available
- I have the latest update of Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630 driver from Intel website
- I tried disabling and enabling that driver but nothing changed
- This laptop model is not supported in our country so, unfortunatly, it is not a legitimate replacement

[A screenshot of my Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOijK.png)

[A screenshot of power options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf9vB.png)

[A screenshot of brightness level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwQ7a.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the Battery Saving mode turned on?

Comment: Have you set the brightness in the Control Panel under Power Options? https://win10drivers.com/images/How-to-fix-brightness-issue.jpg

Comment: Have you installed the appropriate drivers from https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/7571?b=1

Comment: Battery Saving mode is not turned on

Comment: Also update BIOS (UEFI), Chipset and Power Driver. Restart and see if that helps.

Comment: I have updated my post with screenshots of power options and brightness level

Comment: I have already updated BIOS from Acer website long time ago. 
I can't see any newer update on the website.

Comment: Is it a legitimate replacement, or did you just find 'something that fits'? Screen brightness is not a graphics driver issue, it is a hardware recognition issue.

Comment: This model is not supported in our country so, unfortunatly, it isn't a legitimate replacement

Comment: Then why are you surprised the laptop doesn't support all the functionality?

Comment: i see. thank you!